# How to get link to homepage

Tags: templates

I've tried `get_site_url();`, `get_bloginfo('wpurl')` and `home_url();` but they're all giving me a link to the current page rather than the home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );` this best practice.

```
get_bloginfo( $show, $filter );
```

It has lots of Parameters to get info so
let see the **##SHOW(Parameters)**:
name,description,wpurl,url,admin_email,charset,version,html_type,text_direction,language,stylesheet_url,stylesheet_directory,template_url,pingback_url,atom_url,rdf_url,rss_url,rss2_url,comments_atom_url,comments_rss2_url,siteurl,home
so if you want to use this finction you have to use like get_bloginfo('wpurl'); or get_bloginfo('url');

These two functions  home_url() and site_url() return the same value (WordPress address or URL) if WordPress hasn’t been given its own directory.Say you installed a WordPress blog in the root folder of example(dot)com but the core WordPress files was moved to a sub-directory named wp-core.The function home_url() will return example(dot)com and site_url() will return example(dot)com/wp-core.

**A few notes:**

1. home_url() will only return the mapped domain on or after the init has fired. Calling it before then will return the wordpress.com domain.
2. If you accidentally use site_url() in your templates, theme-side links will still redirect correctly to the home_url() equivalent.
3. home_url() is the preferred method, as it avoids the above redirect.

I think you are clear about this what you need to use for your work :)
Happy Coding :)
Musa

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out the answer. It needs to be echo'd, so `echo site_url` works. Or to use in a template `<?= site_url(); ?>`

Comment: It's kinda OT, but I suggest you to avoid short tags (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  Could I recommend that you don't use PHP short open tags though, as instead use the full tag (`<?php`).  Not all servers support them.

Comment: Can I also suggest you take a look at [`bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) and [`get_bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) functions?

Comment: Cheers all. Take your point on the short tags, although the plugin I'm writing requires PHP 5.5 anyway. Worth bearing in mind though.